# Configuring SSIS package error “Cannot find the parameter ‘myParm’ because it does not exist.”

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are using SQL Server 2017.
When I tried to Configure an SSIS package, and set the value of a parameter to something other than the default value from the package, I am getting the error “Cannot find the parameter ‘myParm’ because it does not exist.”

Parameter ‘myParm’ does exist in the SSIS package.

This is the generated SQL:

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_object_parameter_value] @object_type=30, 
@parameter_name=N'myParm', @object_name=N'mySSIS.dtsx', @folder_name=N'myFolder', 
@project_name=N'myProject', @value_type=R, @parameter_value=N'myParmValue'
```

The error is in this statement in the stored procedure set_object_parameter_value

```
SELECT @parameter_id = [parameter_id], @sensitive = [sensitive],
@parameter_data_type = [data_type]
FROM [catalog].[object_parameters]
WHERE [project_id] = @project_id AND [object_type] = @object_type
AND [parameter_name] = @parameter_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND [object_name] = @object_name
```

The weird thing is when I run this statement outside the stored procedure, it runs successfully and return a value for @parameter_id

```
DECLARE @sensitive bit
DECLARE @parameter_id bigint
DECLARE @parameter_data_type nvarchar(128)
SELECT @parameter_id = [parameter_id], @sensitive = [sensitive],
@parameter_data_type = [data_type]
FROM [catalog].[object_parameters]
WHERE [project_id] = 5 AND [object_type] = 30 AND [parameter_name] = 
'myParm' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND [object_name] = 'mySSIS.dtsx'
SELECT @parameter_id
```

But, when I run this statement inside the stored procedure set_object_parameter_value, it gives the same error “Cannot find the parameter ‘myParm’ because it does not exist.”

When I run this statement inside the stored procedure set_object_parameter_value and comment out these 2 lines, it runs successfully

```
WITH EXECUTE AS 'AllSchemaOwner'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
```

I login to SSMS using Windows Authentication myDomain\myAccount

Comment: So that feels like there's a permission issue at play. When you execute the procedure and it errors - what account is running the EXEC? Is it a domain account like faujong@company.com or company\faujong or is it a SQL Server account user = faujong and password = P@ssword1?

Comment: It does sound like a permission issue. When I execute the procedure and it error, I connect to SSMS using Windows Authentication as myself myDomain\myAccount. If I comment out the 2 lines WITH EXECUTE AS 'AllSchemaOwner' and EXECUTE AS CALLER in stored procedure set_object_parameter_value, I can execute the stored proc successfully. The weird thing is this used to work until today